# .mdf file does not respond to SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I have a weird problem with my local database. I added it as a `.mdf` file, and created 2 tables in it.

I tested the connection and the message box states that the connection is working properly.

The problem appears when I try to insert data into that database from my C# application. I tried 2 different ways:

1. By using `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO ....")`
2. By using `.dbml` file (Linq-to-SQL) datacontext

When I try to insert data, no error is thrown, but no data is inserted into the database either. What could be the problem?

I'm using C# in VS 2010 and SQL Server 2005 to make my application

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the view of the database in SQL Management Studio. Go to the database that should have the new tables, select it and then hit F5. There you have your tables! Alternatively if this does not work, post your `ExecNonQuery` code...

Comment: Can you show us your **connection string**? I have a hunch - but I need to see if you really use that approach ...

Comment: This is my connection string: `Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MDC.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True`
I found one very weird thing: I tried to display the data directly from the application by using dataGridView, and it works properly. But still when I close the application and try to query the database manually from VS 2010, it shows that it is empty.

Comment: @NDraskovic when you are looking in VS2010, you are probably looking in the **source** folder. When it executes, it is in a **different** folder (typically the "bin"). And if you run it *again*, it typically copies the file from source to the execute folder (depending on the project settings). Different files in different folders, all different versions of MDC.mdf

Comment: If I'm correct, this should not be the problem when I publish my application and install it on another computer. The database should fill/empty normally like any other, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most perceived problems with MDF files tend to boil down to one of:

- what file have I actually opened?
- is my build/run process actually copying over that file every time I run the application?
- do I have gratuitous error-handling that is swallowing an exception?

Check your connection string, and look in the execution folder (not the project folder), until you are **very** sure which file is being opened. It should get updated after your work (make sure you dispose the connection etc properly).

Also: try fetching the data in a new data-context immediately after the insert, so see if it made it in or not.

Comment: Yes that occurred to me to. Please take a look at the comment I posted in my question.

Comment: @NDraskovic indeed; replied on that